# Building a Spring ConfigurationRetriever to load beans from spring context file for a command line program. How to use @Autowired in this clas?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, autowired

I am building a command-line program in java with the spring framework. Based on the arguments passed into the command-line program the relevant beans would need to be loaded and executed. So I rely on this `ConfigurationRetriever` class I've shown below. But I'm having to do a get bean everywhere in the ConfigurationRetriever (it works fine with calling getBean like I've shown in the code). Ideally I would like  to use @Autowired. How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

```
public class ConfigurationRetriever {
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public ConfigurationRetriever() {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans-service.xml");
    }

    public ServiceNameRunProperties getSearchIndexServices(String service_name) {

        ServiceNameRunPropertiesDao dao = (ServiceNameRunPropertiesDao) context
                .getBean("serviceNameRunPropertiesDaoImpl");

        ServiceNameRunProperties serviceNameRunProperties = new ServiceNameRunProperties();

        serviceNameRunProperties = dao
                .getServiceRunPropertiesByName(service_name);

        return serviceNameRunProperties;
    }

    public String getQueryExecutorService() {
        QueryExecutorService queryExecutorService = (QueryExecutorService) context
                .getBean("queryExecutorImpl");
        return queryExecutorService.executeQuery();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why? Why not simply create a bean which has these injected so you can reduce everything to a single `getBean` call. Why wouldn't you be able to do dependency injection with a command-line app.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I would change the above to support that?

Comment: I just want to use autowired.